# How to make CustomClass savechanges() working in Linq?

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-4

I am trying to get Linq going on Northwind and I am really lost..

I have a CustomClass named `Ordr` with the properties `OrderID, EmployeeID, _ShipRegion`

I do a simple query:

```
        Dim query = From c In dbcontext.Orders _
                Where c.EmployeeID = 2
                Select New Ordr With { _
                    .OrderID = c.OrderID, _
                    .EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID, _
                    .Shipregion = c.ShipRegion}
```

then I bind  this query to a `DataGridView`:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = query
```

Now, when I try to save any changes with `dbcontext.SaveChanges()` no changes are saved.  `OrderID` is the primary key.

How was I supposed to do it properly without loosing the ability to save changes?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, the Entity class is probably called Order and Ordr is just sort of data transfer object. You'll need to save data as an Order object. Example, when you go back to saving, you probably have an updated Ordr class, so convert that into Order class, you might need to attach it to the context or fetch an existing Order based on Id and then update it, and then save the context.
Hope this helps.

Edit in response to the comments:

As an example, you can do this:

```
var orders = from o in context.Orders 
select new Order{Id = o.Id, EmployeeId = o.EmployeeId}; //etc. C#
```

Then when you want to save, this is of type Order, so you should be able to attach it back to the context and save it.

When you return a lighter weight object like Ordr, I am not sure how you can track it automatically, there might be some way, but I have never used them that way. Usually you use them for read-only purposes and to make the query faster.

Comment: Yes, Ordr is a new Object with some, but not all fields from the original Table Order.

Comment: Microsoft implemented a mechanism to track changes whe the query returns the whole table ("select c"), but not when I retrieve some fileds? There is no apparent reason for this to me. That is why I am thinking I am doing something wrong here...

Comment: I think it's not exactly that. In that code snippet, you are creating a new type which is not an Entity object. You can still create a new Order object in the query with few selected properties and that should be trackable, ie, you should be able to attach that to the context and do property change or some similar method.

Comment: I just found this document from microsoft. quote:So far, we have only looked at queries for retrieving entities, objects directly associated with database tables. The beauty of a query language is that you can retrieve information in any form you want. You will not be able to take advantage of automatic change tracking or identity management when you do so. However you can get just the data you want.

Comment: If I missunderstand you, how can I do it?